# Nested schemas in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have just started using sub-document in MongoDB.

I have two schemas

```
childrenSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childrenSchema]
});
```

Should I create a model for each schema or is it best to just have a model for `parentSchema`?

I don't see the advantage of creating a model for each since I don't want to use relational queries.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you create only one `model` for `Parent`, and you can `push` `Child` into that.

In this case, `deleting` parent will automatically `delete` children too. But, If you make another model for Child too, you will have to `delete` all the `children` of a `parent` before you `delete` that `parent`.

**Alternate**

If you don't want to delete a `child` on `deletion` of `Parent`, you should `create` two model, one for `Parent` and another for `Child`, and use `reference` instead of `sub-document` for storing children. This way you wont have to store whole children document in the parent document, just `_id` would do. Later, you can use `mongoose populate` to retrieve information about a child.

```
childrenSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var child = mongoose.model('child',childrenSchema);

parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'child'}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do following in this case.

separate definitions, schemas, models as following:

1) db/definitions.js:

```
const
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,

  Child = {
    name: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      required: true,
      index: true
    }
  },

  Parent = {
    name: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      required: true,
      index: true
    },
    children: {
      type: [ChildSchemaDefinition],
      index: true,
      ref: 'Child';
    }
  };

module.exports = {
  Child,
  Parent
};
```

2) db/schemas.js:

```
const
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  definitions = require('./definitions');
  Child = new Schema(definitions.Child),
  Parent = new Schema(definitions.Parent);

module.exports = {
  Child,
  Parent    
};
```

3) db/models.js:

```
const
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Model = mongoose.model,
  schemas = require('./schemas');

const
  Child = Model('Child', schemas.Child),
  Parent = Model('Parent', schemas.Parent);

module.exports = {
  Child,
  Parent
};
```